# how to take user input where each input is given in new line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose the user gives input on different lines and each line should be processed differently. Example, if i want to count  number of characters of each user given input. Like,if the user gives input on different line as :

```
this is first line
this is second line
this is third line
```

How can i take each line as a new input and store it somewhere and then do some operation(count number of characters) on each input.

Comment: Seems you missed the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Please read it, there is no need to repeat everything here.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputs = [raw_input("enter input data\n") for _ in range(no_of inputs)]
for line in inputs:
   print(len(line))
```

try above code snippet, hope this helps